# Why can't I upvote a post from the Low Quality Posts moderation queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Once in a blue moon there is a good question in the Low Quality Posts moderation queue. Why can't I upvote them without opening the question in a new tab? Am I just missing something? It seems like on this site especially we need to be encouraging MORE upvotes, not making them difficult.

Comment: I've turned this into a feature request, it's something I miss as well now and then.

Comment: @patrix That is a duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191276/upvoting-on-low-quality-posts-in-review-tasks and I'll be there will be more ones SE have rejected

Answer (score 3):

This gives preferential treatment to good, short posts by giving them more exposure, which would introduce extra voting on shorter posts, encouraging users to post shorter posts so that they are upvoted in the queue.

I don't think this is something that should be implemented.